# Drupal 7.22 and Templating

Tags: theming

I am developing a site using drupal. I need to create a template file for a specific page.
For instance this is my site url http://www.dev.com. I created a basic page called documents which URL path settings alias is docs. So what I want to do is that whenever the user clicks on http://www.dev.com/docs drupal should use a specific template file. For that matter I create a tpl file called page--docs.tpl.php and put it inside my theme folder. However drupal seems not loading that file.

PLease assist me if I am missing something.

Comment: have you cleared the cache ?

Comment: Yes I have cleared the cache.

Comment: What is the non-aliased path?

Comment: have you added this in your template.php file function nexus_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
  // If the node type is "blog" the template suggestion will be "page--blog.tpl.php".
   $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. str_replace('_', '--', $vars['node']->type);
  }

Comment: @Bala I have not added that code.

Comment: @rooby: I just add the alias while I was creating the page in drupal through the url path settings feature on the drupal content edit/add page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the non-aliased path for the template name.

For example if you are dealing with node 1 (node ID = 1) try naming the file `page--node--1.tpl.php` and clearing the cache again.

For more info see: https://drupal.org/node/1089656#page-suggestion

If you don't know what the node id is, go to the node edit page and it will be in the url /node/NODEID/edit.

Comment: Please robby do I need to add the code suggested by Bala?

Comment: No, not to have a page template for 1 specific node. His code would allow you to have a template for all nodes of a particular node type.

Comment: @robby : I did as you suggested but the page rendered blank.

Comment: Are there any errors in your web server logs? Often a white screen will mean there is an error in the code of your template. Try with a direct copy of the normal page template with just a minor change like some extra text in the page title or something. Then once it is working make the change you want.

Comment: Thank you all. It is working now. I did as suggested by robby.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly and efficiently find the name to call your template  add the following

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

to you your settings.local.php this will add a comment block before the rendering of your data

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('node') -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
 * node--419.tpl.php
 x node--standard-content-page.tpl.php
 * node.tpl.php
-->
```

for example the above block tells me that if I want to just theme for that one object use the "node--419.tpl.php" for the filename but I chose to make the theme edit available for all objects of the type "standard_content_page"

Ado

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the [page theme module](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_theme) it does exactly what you're looking for using drupal configuration and there's a stable version for drupal 7.

Answer (score -1):

you can also overwrite the template in template.php as well

```
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
$vars['template_files'][] = 'page--docs';
}
```